# How to display two activities in android using multi-window mode?

Tags: android, multi-window

I would like to display two activities side by side using the split view in my app. I have read the content of the below google's site and I am unable to implement the multi-window mode in android nougat. Have anybody implemented that?

Ref: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Android Nougat you can display two activities side by side in same app using **FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_ADJACENT** when launching a new activity.

As per [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window.html)

> When you launch a new activity, you can hint to the system that the
>   new activity should be displayed adjacent to the current one, if
>   possible. To do this, use the intent flag
>   FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_ADJACENT. Passing this flag requests the
>   following behavior:
>
> If the device is in split-screen mode, the system attempts to create
>   the new activity next to the activity that launched it, so the two
>   activities share the screen. The system is not guaranteed to be able
>   to do this, but it makes the activities adjacent if possible. If the
>   device is not in split-screen mode, this flag has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Fragments (see the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)). Fragments are like sub-activities that have their own life cycle, and multiple fragments can be combined in one activity to make a multi-pane user interfaces. Fragments requires Android 3.0 or higher.

Answer (score 1):

Split view or multi-window mode is not meant for activities with an app. This new feature, introduced in Android Nougat, enables display of 2 different apps at the same time.

AFAIK, Android does not currently support displaying 2 activities side by side within an app. However, you may be looking for fragments that can be placed side-by-side in an activity as described [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html).